# How can i get my var in Web3, i always get Promise { <pending> }

Tags: web3js, nodejs

```
var gogo =web3.eth.getBalance("0xXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
.then(console.log);

console.log(gogo);

if (gogo > 123) {
    console.log('enough.');
}
```

how to run if in this case? Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the result in your callback function, after it's returned. Hopefully this helps:

```
// Code here runs first.
web3.eth.getBalance("0xXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
.then(function (gogo) {
  // Code in here runs third, after the call to `getBalance` returns.
  if (gogo > 123) {
    console.log('enough.');
  }
});

// Code here runs second.
console.log('Here!');
```

Comment: How can i know the sort of these unit? Functions alaways are Later because return?

Comment: This is just how asynchronous JavaScript works.